# Facebook account to replace registration?

Tags: facebook, authentication, passwords, registration

I'm new to all this. This is what i'm after and i'm sure it's possible.

I've got a script where people can register/login in to as members. What i'd like to do is tie it in so that it just uses Facebook users details for the registrations. I've managed to set it up to sign up and and complete a registration using a user's name and email.

What i'd like to do now is automatically log the user in if they're logged in on facebook, is this possible or will they need to click a login button that then takes them to their page? If they need to click a button to login, how do I go about getting the button to take their facebook details and log them in? Also what happens in regards to passwords on my site? Is that stored in the app somehow?

Ideally i'd like to use the popup version of verification rather than the iframe that i've got set up at the moment.

Cheers in advanced for any help for a n00b!

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact possible. Although I for my part was never a fan of such things here's some human-readable (simplified) theory:

Facebook uses a system called OAuth ( http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth ). That means, when you want to have the user login onto your site using Facebook you'll of course need to provide a button/facebook-login-frame (see documentation) that says "Log me in with Facebook" or so. You then access Facebooks API (more here: https://developers.facebook.com/ ) and basically tell Facebook who you are ("Hi I'm website XY"). While that happens your user is redirected to Facebooks "permission-landing-page". On that page he needs to confirm whether he is fine with your website accessing certain information (like his name). If he confirms your website receives an access-token granting you access to a subset of his user information which you can then use to personalize his expeirence on your website.

Check out facebooks documentation because they explain exactly your usecase in detail.
(here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ )

PS: You'll of course never have any access to his Facebook login/password. That's kind of the idea behind "delegating" the authentication via OAuth to Facebook. Facebook only provides you with an access token (bound to that particular user who logged in and granted your app/website permissions)

Comment: Thanks for this, as I said i'm a bit n00b to the facebook coding side of things so don't really understand it, i'll give it a bash.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how much you know in the end but without some decent intermediate knowledge in ... say PHP, HTML and JS aswell as some theory behind how API's work you'll have trouble implementing that stuff.